# Does connecting to a multi-battle partner in the Battle Mansion reset your streak?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

My friend and I always played the multi battles in Black & White 1 and we got some long streaks out of them. This was only possible because we could save our streak every 7 matches. Now I've heard that connecting with a partner resets your streak (it said so on Serebii).

So does this mean it is impossible for us to go for a longer streak, spread over a few weeks?

Comment: Honestly, I'd say try it and see :p Do a few battles, suspend your challenge properly, and see if it gets reset when you play again. Then, post your findings here so we know too ;)

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it does not reset your streak if you connect or disconnect from a partner.

I just tested this with a friend of mine.

1. My friend and I went into Multi-battle together.

   - We both had a win streak of '1'
2. We paused the challenge by clicking the 'Take a Break' option.

   - Interacting with the receptionist separately, we both still had a '1' win streak
3. We reconnected, Battle #2

   - Both of us still had the streak, and the battle counted as Win #2
4. We disconnected again
5. My friend battled alone with an NPC (Archie).

   - He still had his previous streak of '2'
   - The win counted as Win #3 for him
6. He quit with Archie and we reconnected and multi-battled

   - He still had his streak of 3
   - I still had a streak of 2.
   - After the battle, his streak was 4, mine was 3.

So it doesn't matter whether you are multi-battling with NPCs or another player, so long as you continue to win, your streak will continue to grow.